# round off column value in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rdbms

I'm trying to round off column value with 2 decimal places.

```
create table ABC("NUM" real);----------created table

insert into ABC values(22.567333335555555); ---------inserted values
```

however I tried this query

```
select ROUND("NUM:,2) from ABC;
```

And getting the below Error message

```
ERROR:  function round(real, integer) does not exist
LINE 1:  select ROUND("NUM",2) from ABC;
```

I want to display the Answer should be two decimal value like as

```
NUM
-----
22.56
```

Comment: The round() function doesn't work with real (float4), but will if you cast it to double precision (float8) or numeric. `SELECT round("NUM"::float8,2) FROM abc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this it is working for me

```
 SELECT round( CAST("NUM" as numeric), 2) FROM ABC;
```

Comment: i want to display for whole the column values(i have inserted 10 values in NUM column), i could not pass the value for each time to display the column .

Comment: I also worked on postgres.But i did not use any where.Now i searched for this

Comment: ok its fine and also i have questioned one more question title is Scalability of postgresql. if you come to know the answer please let me know your suggestion.